# Adding a method to a domain class

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a domain class containing a couple of fields. I can access them from my .gsps. I want to add a method to the domain class, which I can call from the .gsps (this method is a kind of virtual field; it's data is not coming directly from the database).

How do I add the method and how can I then call it from the .gsps?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To add a method, just write it out like you would any other regular method. It will be available on the object when you display it in your GSP.

```
def someMethod() {
  return "Hello."
}
```

Then in your GSP.

```
${myObject.someMethod()}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want your method to appear to be more like a property, then make your method a getter method.  A method called getFullName(), can be accessed like a property as ${person.fullName}.  Note the lack of parentheses.

Comment: I would think you merely put a get on the front i.e. `def getSomeMethod()`.

Answer (score 4):

Consider class like below

class Job {

```
String jobTitle
String jobType
String jobLocation
String state



static constraints = {

    jobTitle nullable : false,size: 0..200
    jobType nullable : false,size: 0..200
    jobLocation nullable : false,size: 0..200
    state nullable : false


}



def jsonMap () {
    [
         'jobTitle':"some job title",
         'jobType':"some jobType",
         'jobLocation':"some location",
         'state':"some state"
    ]
    }
```

}

You can use that jsonMap wherever you want. In gsp too like ${jobObject.jsonMap()}